# How to obtain the 6- and 12-gon with 6 equal rectangles?

Tags: geometry

Let's say you have 6 equal business cards. 
How can you place them on a table to create these shapes:

- regular hexagon
- regular dodecagon

**Edit.** 
Feel free to propose an answer for options:
a) you have 50-by-90 units rectangles,
b) the sizes of rectangles doesn't have matter.

Comment: What are the dimensions of these cards?

Comment: @deusovi, it does not matter, for instance, 90 by 50 mm.

Comment: Do we need to cover the whole interior of the polygon? Or is it enough to create a boundary that has the shape?

Comment: @sedrick, boudary for 6-gon, and vertecies for 12-gon

Comment: @dooper, could you please add answer with a sketch?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> With the right sized rectangles, a hexagon can be made with just three cards, otherwise with 6 cards a hexagon is quite easy.
>  The dodecagon requires 12 points, so each card has to provide two points to the shape. So half of the cards for the hexagon can simply be 'rotated' 30°.
>  The ratio for the 'perfect rectangle' for making a hexagon with three cards is 1:√3
>  [image]
>  With the right sized rectangles, a dodecagon can be filled perfectly too.
>  [image]

Comment: Your answer is very good. But how one can define 30°? Also I see the solution in bottom figure includes rectangles which size are not  business cards. Could you please give some extensions?

Comment: @Nick You said in a comment on the question that the size/dimensions doesn't matter.

Comment: The four initial diagrams use cards 90 * 50. The last diagram was more of an extra thing, since it's not business card size. (I think it's about half business card size)

Comment: @randal'thor, you are right. In the comment I wrote that the size does not matter because I have the solution for a regular 6-gon and doesn't have the solution for a regular 12-gon. I am omitting the size's requirement. But after the Matthew Jensen's answer I hope that someone can solve the puzzle for business cards too.

Comment: @matthewjensen, if a=50, b=90, then tan(alpha)=a/b. And alpha approximately equals 30 degrees.

Comment: @Nick Yes, the 'perfect rectangle' I mentioned is very close to business card size, that's why the top left diagram appears very close to a perfect hexagon.

Answer (score 2):

I hopped onto google drawings to make the sketch you asked for. If all you want is the boundary than making a hexagon is very simple. I feel like I am missing some aspect of this...

[image]

Comment: @dooper, how to proof that 6-gon is regular?

Comment: All sides are equal. This is given because all the cards have the exact same dimensions. To be regular, all that is left is to make all the angles equal. This cannot be proven, since it is possible to construct a hexagon with equal sides but different angles. Thus, it is up to the person constructing this to actually make the angles equal.